# Chunkvnc - Instantsupport.exe shown as malware

Tags: google-chrome, security, remote-desktop, tightvnc, ultravnc

We are using [Chunkvnc](http://www.chunkvnc.com/) from a long time. But it is shown as malicious by so many antivirus. I have Instantsupport.exe in my website which my customers download to connect us remotely. But when file is downloaded by using google chrome it shows that file is malicious. When i checked in webmaster tools of google it was showing that Instantsupport.exe is malicious. So now google chrome shows error as malicious for any file downloaded from my website.It is because of the Instantsupport.exe which is considered as malware by google, now shows same message for all files downloaded from my website. So i want to know what is the problem with this Chunkvnc? How it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is common to various VNC programs, as they can be used maliciously. The problem is that they are mostly used for remote access and administration, and antivirus programs still flag them, generally as "potentially unwanted", but sometimes under a more general malware category.

In some cases just trying to open a VNC port is enough to cause an alert of some kind. IRC clients also have this problem, as many botnets connect to IRC servers for command and control.

There is no good solution, other than making it very clear to whoever is downloading/running the program that it is NOT malicious, but many AV programs say otherwise. I cannot give advice on how to explain that to someone who is inclined to believe otherwise.